# What is the limit (length) of an order's notes?

Tags: order, commerce-cloud, notes

When I am adding a note to an order.

```
order.addNote('Title of the note', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

I am getting this error: **Text length 4103 > 4000**

I didn't find any explanation for this in the Salesforce documentation.
What is the best way to truncate/limit it?

Comment: What is `order.addNote` writing to that has a 4000 character limit? Classic `Note.Body` is 32k, as is `Order.Description`. `ContentNote.Content` is 50*MB*. Seems like maybe it's a custom Long Text Area field that has a character limit on it?

Comment: It is about this: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_order_LineItemCtnr.html#dw_order_LineItemCtnr_addNote_String_String_DetailAnchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SFCC Documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_order_LineItemCtnr.html#dw_order_LineItemCtnr_addNote_String_String_DetailAnchor) says:

> text - The text of the note. Must be no more than 4000 characters or an exception is thrown.

To handle this and split the content into more than a 4000 character note, if needed:

```
//Add order note.
Transaction.wrap(function () {
  let orderStr = JSON.stringify(orderRequestData.data);
  if (orderStr !== null) {
    if (orderStr.length <= 4000) {
      order.addNote('Order Export JSON', JSON.stringify(orderRequestData.data));
    } else {
      let index = 1;
      let startIndex = 0;
      let endIndex = 4000;
      let slice = orderStr.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
      while (!empty(slice)) {
        order.addNote('Order Export JSON ' + index, slice);
        startIndex += 4000;
        endIndex += 4000;
        index++;
        slice = orderStr.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
      }
    }
  }
});
```